# Good jQuery Content Switcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Does anyone know of a good jQuery content switcher?  I want to switch a log in and register form.

Comment: You could try one like this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-content-panel-switcher/

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like this with minimal code, for example if you had:

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="#login">Login</a>
  <a href="#register">Register</a>
</div>

<div id="login" class="panels">
  Login Stuff
</div>
<div id="register" class="panels">
  Registration Stuff
</div>
```

You could do jQuery like this:

```
$(".links a").click(function() {
  $(".panels").hide();
  $(this.hash).fadeIn();
});
```

Just hide both initially with CSS if you wanted, like this:

```
.panels { display: none; }
```

When you clicked either link above, it would hide the other panels, and fade in the one you wanted to switch to for a nice effect...use the same convention as above and you could add any number of panels and links.

Some other pre-built alternatives if you want more complicated content arrangement would be something like:

- [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)
- [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/)

Comment: +1 Which is probably what the switcher would do in 30KB of code.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  My source:

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".links a").click(function() {
  $(".panels").hide();
  $(this.hash).fadeIn();
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.panels { display: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="links">
  <a href="#login">Login</a>
  <a href="#register">Register</a>

</div>

<div id="login" class="panels">
  Login Stuff
</div>
<div id="register" class="panels">
  Regist
</body>
</html>

Comment: @Christopher - The html you posted is missing the `</div>` for the `<div id="register">`, add this and it should work, here's a full example of what you posted running: http://jsfiddle.net/PbkyG/